# Django accessing database

Tags: django, django-models

When using the following LIMIT clause in the Django models API --

`People.objects.all()[5000000:5000000+5]`

Does the database have to go through all 5M records in order to return just these 5 records? Or is it non-linear in its access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will go at least through the index table for the primary key of your `People` table. This question has in my opinion nothing to do about how Django handles this. Django will handle it as your database will. Django's ORM will just transform it into a query similiar to this one:

`SELECT * FROM peoples OFFSET 5000000 LIMIT 5;`

Answer (score 0):

In short it does do a scan until that point and get the number of records you specify. This actually depends on your database, different databases have different performance on this query. It is not a random access, you should expect the same records to be returned if you do this 5 times, assuming your data has not changed. If you do an order_by you'd have even more predictable results.

Comment: Sorry, I meant non-linear access, not random-access. This should make the question more clear.